# Application is crashed due to Xamarin.CarouselView in xamarin android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have very tied to find out the reason of unexpectedly closing of my xamarin android project. I have used CarouselView in xaml page. When I am navigate to that page application is crashed unexpectedly but it works fine when I run ios project. Actually I am working on portable project. Can you please suggest any idea of this issue. I have posted the my hockeyapp crash report. I think it will help to identify, what the exact cause.Thanks in advance.

Here is hockey app crash report

[image]

Here is my code

```
 <cv:CarouselView VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions = 
 "FillAndExpand" Position = "{Binding DishCategory}" ItemSelected = 
 "OnSwipeDishesHandler" ItemsSource = "{Binding RestaurantDishesList}" 
 x:Name = "RestaurantDishesList">

     <cv:CarouselView.HeightRequest>
      <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="230" Tablet ="630"/>
                    </cv:CarouselView.HeightRequest>
                    <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout Padding = "10,5,10,5" Orientation = "Vertical">
                          <ListView x:Name="RestaurantMenuListView" BackgroundColor="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryWiseDishes}" HasUnevenRows="true" SeparatorColor="#eeeeee" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                              <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                  <StackLayout Padding="7">
                                    <Grid Padding="2">
                                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                      <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnMenuItemSelected"/>
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black">
                                          <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="15" Tablet ="20"/>
                                          </Label.FontSize>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="#323232">
                                          <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="11" Tablet ="16"/>
                                          </Label.FontSize>
                                        </Label>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                          <Label Text="£" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FontSize>
                                              <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="14" Tablet ="19"/>
                                            </Label.FontSize>
                                          </Label>
                                          <Label Text="{Binding Cost}" TextColor="Black">
                                            <Label.FontSize>
                                              <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="14" Tablet ="19"/>
                                            </Label.FontSize>
                                          </Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                      </StackLayout>
                                      <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Image Source="minus.png">
                                          <Image.WidthRequest>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="25" Tablet ="35"/>
                                          </Image.WidthRequest>
                                          <Image.HeightRequest>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="25" Tablet ="35"/>
                                          </Image.HeightRequest>
                                          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="RemoveItemBtnClicked"/>
                                          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding TotalQuantity}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black">
                                          <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                              <OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="13" Android="13" WinPhone="13" />
                                              </OnIdiom.Phone>
                                              <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="15" Android="15" WinPhone="15" />
                                              </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            </OnIdiom>
                                          </Label.FontSize>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Image Source="add.png">
                                          <Image.WidthRequest>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="25" Tablet ="35"/>
                                          </Image.WidthRequest>
                                          <Image.HeightRequest>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments ="x:Double" Phone ="25" Tablet ="35"/>
                                          </Image.HeightRequest>
                                          <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="AddItemBtnClicked"/>
                                          </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Image>
                                      </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                  </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                              </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                          </ListView>
                        </StackLayout>
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                  </cv:CarouselView>
```

Comment: The top line says it all: something is being divided by zero. And without any code it is next to impossible to determine what happens.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, I have updated the code. Can please check once.